# Why can't I pass a function handle to fsolve, but I can write an equivalent anonymous function in fsolve?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I find this somewhat odd. I am currently writing a simple function to solve a system of equations using `fsolve.` Here is what I have:

```
%Variable Declarations
 I0 = 10e-12;
 n = 1;
 Vt = 0.0259;
 R = 10e3;
 Vs = 3;

 %Function 1 (Some may recognize that this is the Shockley Diode Equation, if anyone cares...)
  i1 = @(v1)(I0) * (exp((v1)/(n*Vt))-1);

 %Function 2
 i2 = @(v1) ((Vs-v1)/R);

 %This is what I originally tried
 h = @(v1) i1(v1)-i2(v1);

 fsolve(h(v1), 1)

 %After running this, I receive "Undefined function or variable 'v1.'"
 % However, if I write

 fsolve(@(v1)i1(v1)-i2(v1),1)

 %The function works. With the result, I plugged that value into h(v1), and it produces the expected result (very close to 0)
```

That said, why doesn't `matlab` allow me to pass a function handle to `fsolve`?

Comment: use fsolve(h, 1) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass a function handle, which is `h`, not `h(v1)`. `h(v1)` itself can't be evaluated because `v1` is not defined.

Try `fsolve(h, 1)`

Comment: Yes, that definitely works. I suppose I was thinking it must be `h(v1)` because of how I typically use anonymous functions. Thanks.